# How to automate SLA validation using Jmeter in Non-GUI mode, i.e. using command line jmeter utility

Tags: jmeter

How can I do create SLA goals and validate SLAs using Jmeter from command line ? Please help, I want to be able to throw this command line script on Jenkins and fail/pas the build based on SLA validation, if SLA goals aren't met the build should just fail.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) - you have the handful of options to mark the build as failed or unstable basing on response times.
2. If you need to fail the script based on other metrics, the easiest option is running JMeter via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) framework. It has flexible and powerful [Pass/Fail Criteria](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) subsystem and in case of test failure you will have non-zero command-line process exit code so Jenkins will automatically mark the step as failed.

Comment: I used the Jenkins Performance Plugin but it marks the build failed based on response time only like you said, but no other options. How about Average Transactions Per Second; TPS ? Can I find more graphs using some other jmeter plugin ?